# Writing an ActiveRecord/AREL query to select the coin held by the greatest numbers of users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

Just to explain: I have the following models and associations:

```
User      has_many   :portfolios
          has many   :positions, through: portfolios
Portfolio has_many   :positions
Position  belongs_to :coin
Coin      has_many   :positions
```

I want to select the coin that is held by the greatest number of users, but am struggling a bit to come up with the correct query. I could imagine writing something like 'find the coin that has the most positions, where the user_ids of the positions are distinct'. Is that the right idea, and how does one type that up?

EDIT:

```
def number_of_users
  count = 0
  User.all.each do |user|
    if user.positions.any?{|pos| pos.coin_id == self.id}
      count += 1
    end
  end
  return count
end

def self.with_most_holders
  self.all.max_by {|coin| coin.number_of_users}
end
```

Comment: hey, have you solved your problem?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help, I wrote two methods in Coin class that will do the job, but I like your version too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to achieve what you want:

```
Coin
  .joins(positions: { portfolio: :user })
  .group("coins.id")
  .order("COUNT(DISTINCT(users.id)) DESC")
  .first
```

Comment: Thanks! I just edited my question to make the associations a bit clearer.  Does that affect your answer?

Comment: @user211309 edited the answer, I think (having corresponding `belongs_to`) you could make it work with `Coin.joins(positions: :user)...`. But this should do as well